# Is ReadOnlyCollection<char> immutable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

With the code below i get a [CA2104 (DoNotDeclareReadOnlyMutableReferenceTypes) warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182302%28VS.80%29.aspx)

```
public readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> IllegalChars;
```

with part of the error message

> change the field to one that is an
>   immutable reference type. If the
>   reference type
>   'ReadOnlyCollection' is, in
>   fact, immutable, exclude this message.

I am sure ReadOnlyCollection is immutable but my question is is there a type can i use to not have this message appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the public field to a property:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<char> IllegalChars { get; private set; }
```

or exclude the Code Analysis warning, because the collection can't be changed. The problem is that FxCop is unable to detect that the `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` is actually immutable.

Comment: kind of irrelevant but if its immutable is there a reason for it to be a property?

Comment: @acidzombie24: Yes, in the future you might want `IllegalChars` to do some extra work before returning the `ReadOnlyCollection<>`. You can't do that if `IllegalChars` is a field.

Answer (score 2):

> I am sure ReadOnlyCollection is immutable.

It's immutable in the sense that you can't change what collection it wraps, or change that collection through it.

It's not immutable in the sense that because `ReadOnlyCollection` is a wrapper, it can be mutated by mutating the underlying collection:

```
var list = new List<char>{ 'a', 'b', 'c' };
var ro = new ReadOnlyCollection<char>(list);
list.Add('d');
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", ro)); // a,b,c,d
```

However, you certainly can have a `ReadOnlyCollection` that is immutable in practice, by not having a reference to the underlying collection anywhere (easiest way is to copy it upon construction, or to only construct that collection when first constructing the readonly wrapper and then not having another reference).

Doing so will mean that you are keeping in the spirit of CA2104, in that you are immune from the sort of problems it's intended to save you from. It would then be reasonable to suppress the warning.

I'd be cautious of public fields more generally, favouring properties unless I was really sure I wanted a field, but that's another matter.